# How to change background color of a whole section in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, background-color, uicollectionview

In UICollectionView, I want to give the whole section a uniform background color, instead of for a single cell or for the whole collection view.

I don't see any delegate method to do that, any suggestions?

Comment: try this https://github.com/devxoul/UICollectionViewFlexLayout

Answer (score 15):

First, make a UICollectionReusableView to be your background view. I've simply set mine to be red.

```
class SectionBackgroundDecorationView: UICollectionReusableView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then, in YourCollectionViewController:

```
static let background = "background-element-kind"

init() {
    super.init(collectionViewLayout: YourCollectionViewController.createLayout())
}

static func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex: Int,
        layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        
        // Use sectionIndex to control the layout in each section
        if sectionIndex == 0 {
            
            // Customise itemSize, item, groupSize, group to be whatever you want
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                                                  heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
       
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                                                   heightDimension: .absolute(170))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])

            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            
            // Create a sectionBackground
            let sectionBackground = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(
                    elementKind: background)

            section.decorationItems = [sectionBackground]
            return section
            
        } else {
            
          // Your layout for other sections, etc
          // You don't have to set a background for other sections if you don't want to
        }
    }
    layout.register(SectionBackgroundDecorationView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: background)
    return layout
}
```

These links to documentation helped me:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutdecorationitem
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayoutsectionprovider

Comment: Is there a way to give different background colours to different sections based on the sectionData ?

Answer (score 12):

The new `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` introduced in iOS 13 have a property named `decorationItems` for adding decoration items conveniently, which you could use to add a background for the section.

```
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.decorationItems = [
   NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind:"your identifier")
]
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to override **UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes** to add a color attribute. And then override **UICollectionReusableView** apply the color to the view background.

https://github.com/strawberrycode/SCSectionBackground

Comment: When i make this example to support all orientation, while moving from portratoit to landscappre or vice versa the app crashes with below error,

Comment: SCSectionBackground[34266:300939] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layout attributes for supplementary item at index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) changed from <SCSectionBackground.SCSBCollectionViewLayoutAttributes: index path: (< {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (sectionBackground); frame = (0 0; 667 116); zIndex = -1; to <SCSectionBackground.SCSBCollectionViewLayoutAttributes:> index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (sectionBackground); frame = (0 0; 375 116); zIndex = -1;

Comment: without invalidating the layout'. Could you help to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this out yet, but it looks to me that you need to use decoration views if you want a background behind your cells (like the shelf in the Books app). I think you should be able to have different views for each section, and set them up using the delegate method `layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:atIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 2):

refer to:
[strawberrycode: Use DecorationView as 
 background](https://github.com/strawberrycode/SCSectionBackground)
[devxoul: Use SupplementaryElement as background](https://github.com/devxoul/UICollectionViewFlexLayout)
[airbnb: Use SupplementaryElement as background](https://github.com/airbnb/MagazineLayout)

I need to compatible with `IGListKit`, so I use `decorationView` as 
 background. The layout is subclass from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` for common use case. [My implementation](https://gist.github.com/yanpanpan/23648e1fadd773466a001a3529d6fb46):
[image: different section background]

Answer (score 0):

In collection view every section can have a supplementary views, so put supplementary views for each section then set background color to supplementary views instead of section cells. I hope it will help.

Comment: When reading about supplementary views, I only find examples when it is used for headers & footers. Do you have any example and/or working code for your answer.

Comment: I have done it by using collection view custom layout. In custom layout my supplementary view frame is equal to that entire section frame.

Comment: How did you manage to do that? if you could tell that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the classic approach is to create a Custom Supplementary Kind and provide your custom view in CollectionView Section background. It will give you the ability to customize section backgrounds.
Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63598373/14162081

Answer (score -1):

I went off of this repo here https://github.com/SebastienMichoy/CollectionViewsDemo/tree/master/CollectionViewsDemo/Sources/Collections%20Views

**Swift 3**

subclass uicollectionreusableview

```
class SectionView: UICollectionReusableView {
   static let kind = "sectionView"
}
```

subclass uicollectionViewFlowLayout

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

// MARK: Properties

var decorationAttributes: [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
var sectionsWidthOrHeight: [IndexPath: CGFloat]


// MARK: Initialization

override init() {
    self.decorationAttributes = [:]
    self.sectionsWidthOrHeight = [:]

    super.init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.decorationAttributes = [:]
    self.sectionsWidthOrHeight = [:]

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

// MARK: Providing Layout Attributes

override func layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return self.decorationAttributes[indexPath]
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
    let numberOfSections = self.collectionView!.numberOfSections
    var xOrYOffset = 0 as CGFloat

    for sectionNumber in 0 ..< numberOfSections {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: sectionNumber)
        let numberOfItems = self.collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: sectionNumber)
        let sectionWidthOrHeight = numberOfItems == 0 ? UIScreen.main.bounds.height : collectionViewContentSize.height//self.sectionsWidthOrHeight[indexPath]!
        let decorationAttribute = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: SectionView.kind, with: indexPath)
        decorationAttribute.zIndex = -1

        if self.scrollDirection == .vertical {
            decorationAttribute.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: xOrYOffset, width: self.collectionViewContentSize.width, height: sectionWidthOrHeight)
        } else {
            decorationAttribute.frame = CGRect(x: xOrYOffset, y: 0, width: sectionWidthOrHeight, height: self.collectionViewContentSize.height)
        }

        xOrYOffset += sectionWidthOrHeight

        attributes?.append(decorationAttribute)
        self.decorationAttributes[indexPath] = decorationAttribute
    }

    return attributes
}
}
```

implement this

**CollectionView delegate function**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) {

    Log.printLog(identifier: elementKind, message: indexPath)
    if elementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, let view = view as? ProfileViewHeaderView {

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (102 / 255.0), green: (169 / 255.0), blue: (251 / 255.0), alpha: 1)
    } else if elementKind == SectionView.kind {
        let evenSectionColor = UIColor.black
        let oddSectionColor = UIColor.red

        view.backgroundColor = (indexPath.section % 2 == 0) ? evenSectionColor : oddSectionColor
    }
}
```

**This is important**

```
let layout = CustomFlowLayout()
layout.register(SectionView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: SectionView.kind)
```

register the UICollectionReusableView with layout not collectionView.

one more thing. I messed around with the height in layoutAttributesForElements. you should change it for your own project.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple just use this default UICollectionViewDelegate's method, it will works

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.item)

    let evenSectionColor = UIColor.clear
    let oddSectionColor = UIColor.white
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = (indexPath.item % 2 == 0) ? evenSectionColor : oddSectionColor

}
```

Answer (score -4):

I have changed the background color of each section in a very simple manner in the following method: But I was not sure whether it is the right thing to do. But it did work.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FamilyCalendarCellItemCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"calendarItem" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Event *event;
    _headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:
                   UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"EventHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath]; //headerView is declared as property of Collection Reusable View class
    if(indexPath.section==0) {

        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
        }
    else if(indexPath.section==1) {

        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This only changes the background colour of the cells. The question is asking for how to change the background colour of the collection view itself within a given section