# How to add a background image to UICollectionView that will scroll and zoom will cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm building a mosaic view using `UICollectionView`.

I have subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to layout a fixed grid that can be scrolled both **horizontally and vertically**. I have also attached a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` so the collection can scaled/zoomed.

Each cell in the collection contains a `UIImage` with some transparency. I want to add a background image that will scroll and zoom with the cells.

I've attempted a number of different solutions.

- setting the background color of the `UICollectionView` using **`colorWithPatternImage`**. (*does not scroll/resize with content*)
- setting a background image view on each cell to the relevant cropped portion of the background image. (*uses far too much memory*)

I've been looking into Supplementary and Decoration Views but struggling to get my head around it. I think I need to use *Supplementary* views as the image used in the background will change depending on the `datasource`.

What I don't understand is how I can register just one Supplementary View to span the width and height of the whole `collectionview`. They seem to be tied to an `indexPath` i.e each cell.

Comment: A potential solution might be to put the image in a scroll view behind the collection view, and every time the user scrolls the collection view, you manually set the background scroll view to match.

Comment: Thanks @nhgrif, this is one solution I have considered but seemed a bit inelegant.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if you found an answer...!

You're on the right track with wanting to use supplementary views. The index path of the supplementary view isn't tied to a cell, it has its own index path.

Then in your subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` you need to subclass a few methods. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind%3aatIndexPath%3a) are pretty good!

In the [`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/layoutAttributesForElementsInRect%3a) method you'll need to call super and then add another set of layout attributes for your supplementary view.

Then in the [`layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind%3aatIndexPath%3a) method you set the size of the returned attributes to the size of the collection view content so the image fills all the content, and not just the frame. You also probably want to set the z-order to, to make sure it's behind the cells. See the docs for [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes/layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind%3awithIndexPath%3a)

```
@implementation CustomFlowLayout

    -(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        NSMutableArray *attributes = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy];

        // Use your own index path and kind here
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *backgroundLayoutAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:@"background" atIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithItem:0 inSection:0]];

        [attributes addObject:backgroundLayoutAttributes];

        return [attributes copy];
    }

    -(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

        if ([kind isEqualToString:@"background"]) {
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attrs = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withIndexPath:indexPath];
            attrs.size = [self collectionViewContentSize];
            attrs.zIndex = -10;
            return attrs;
        } else {
            return [super layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }

@end
```

In your collection view data source you need this method:
[`collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDataSource/collectionView%3aviewForSupplementaryElementOfKind%3aatIndexPath%3a)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup your collection view
    UICollectionView *collectionView = [UICollectionView initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:[CustomFlowLayout new]];
    [collectionView registerClass:[BackgroundReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:@"background" withReuseIdentifier:@"backgroundView"];
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([kind isEqualToString:@"background"]) {
        BackgroundReusableView *view = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"backgroundView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Set extra info

        return view;
    } else {
        // Shouldn't be called
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Hopefully all that should get you on the right track :)

Answer (score 2):

To implement custom section background in CollectionView in Swift 5,

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        
        for section in 0..<collectionView!.numberOfSections{
            let backgroundLayoutAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes = layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: "background", at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)) ?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()
            attributes?.append(backgroundLayoutAttributes)
        }
        return attributes
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attrs = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: elementKind, with: indexPath)
        if elementKind == "background"{
            attrs.size = collectionView!.contentSize
            
            //calculate frame here
            let items = collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section)
            let totalSectionHeight:CGFloat = CGFloat(items * 200)
            let cellAttr = collectionView!.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
            attrs.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cellAttr!.frame.origin.y, width: collectionView!.frame.size.width, height: totalSectionHeight)
            
            attrs.zIndex = -10
            return attrs
        }else{
            return super.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: elementKind, at: indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

In your CollectionView DataSource,

```
          override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    
            //register collection view here
           ...

            //setup flow layout & register supplementary view        
            let customFlowLayout = CustomFlowLayout()
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout = customFlowLayout
            collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "BackgroundReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "background", withReuseIdentifier: "BackgroundReusableView")


}


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
            if kind == "background"{
                let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "BackgroundReusableView", for: indexPath) as! BackgroundReusableView
                return view
            }
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
```