# How to add a background image to a UICollectionViewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, image, swift, background, uicollectionviewcell

I had assumed that it would be easy to add a background image to a `UICollectionViewCell`, but I am having trouble figuring it out. I have a border image like this that I want to add to every cell in my `UICollectionView`.

`border.png`

[image]

I couldn't see an option to add it in the Interface Builder and I'm not sure which method to use on `UICollectionViewCell` programmatically.

I have seen these similar questions:

- [UICollectionView Cell with Image, change Background with click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187166/uicollectionview-cell-with-image-change-background-with-click) (image is already added)
- [How to add a background image to UICollectionView that will scroll and zoom will cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161823/how-to-add-a-background-image-to-uicollectionview-that-will-scroll-and-zoom-will) (`UICollectionView`, not `UICollectionViewCell`)

Comment: I tried adding it in IB, but there wasn't a similar way to add it like I would with a UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a UIImageView to your CollectionViewCell and set this image as the image.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a old question, with an accepted answer. But why not just set the border of the cell like so:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4

  return cell
}
```

That way you don't need to use a image. Just adjust the borderWidth and cornerRadius until you get the desired effect.

Comment: I think when I wrote the question I still hadn't learned how to do borders on a layer. I subsequently added that as an update to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31735229/3681880). So yes, your answer here is a better solution to my original problem (+1 for that). But since my question asked how to add a background image, I should keep the accepted answer. Not all background images will necessarily be a border.

Answer (score 4):

```
let View=UIView()
View.backgroundColor=UIColor(patternImage:UIImage(named:"border.png")!)
cell.backgroundView=View
```

in `uicollectionview` `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method

Comment: Not using IB is ok, too. I couldn't figure out either way, so this way is helpful to know, too.