# Set a background color for a UICollectionView section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I would like to set a background color for the entire section in a `UICollectionView`. I want the area between **"Header"** and **"Footer"** to have a different background color than the background color of the  `UICollectionView` itself.

[image]

I made this drawing to clarify what I want. I want something like the green background color inside the red rectangle. Is there a way to set a `UIView` behind the cells so I can color this view?

Comment: it is a duplicate. but the link you posted has no accepted answer so far..

Comment: https://github.com/devxoul/UICollectionViewFlexLayout

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out yet, but it look to me that you need to use decoration views if want a background behind you cells (like the shelf in the Books app). I think you should be able to have different views for each section, and set them up using the `delegate` method, `layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:atIndexPath:`.

Thanks to @rdelmar in [How to change background color of a whole section in UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609204/how-to-change-background-color-of-a-whole-section-in-uicollectionview)

Comment: Put it as duplicate, Or at least explain more with consisting of the copied answer .

Comment: I have put it as a duplicate already